# primefaces style apply only to nested elements

Tags: css, primefaces

For removing the padding inside a Tab of the Primefaces TabView component, I created a new style on my css file:

```
.tabviewleft .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel {
    padding: 0px 0px;
}
```

Then I tryed to apply this new style to the Tab. But it didn't work:

```
<p:tab id="fieldCategoryTab" title="category" styleClass="tabviewleft" >
```

Then I tryed applying on the TabView component. But it didn't work too:

```
<p:tabView id="tabViewLeft" styleClass="tabviewleft">
```

Then I created a div outside the TabView and it worked:

```
<div id="teste" class="tabviewleft">
```

Why I need to create a div outside the TabView to apply the style?

Is it possible to apply it directly to the Tab or TabView without creating a div?

Thank you in advance for any explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible .
Suppose your `<p:tabView>`'s structure is like :

```
<p:tabView id="tabView" styleClass="tabView" dynamic="true" 
    cache="false"> 

    <p:tab title="#{trhBundle['paidLeave']}" id="paid">
       <h:form>
       </h:form>
    </p:tab>

    <p:tab title="#{trhBundle['RTT']}" id="rtt">
       <h:form>
       </h:form>
    </p:tab>

    <p:tab title="#{trhBundle['specialLeave']}" id="special">
       <h:form>
       </h:form>
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

Then add css

```
.tabView .ui-tabs-panel {
padding: 0px!important;
}
```

I think this will remove all padding of `<p:tab>`.